# How to achieve VLOOKUP function in MS Access DB?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I've got a MS Access DB as follow:

Employee_Table:

```
Employee_ID     Employee_Name
     1              Rachel
     2              Jordan
     3              Chris
```

Event_Table:

```
Event_ID     Employee_ID    Employee_Name
    1                           Rachel
    2                           Rachel
    3                           Rachel
    4                           Jordan
```

How could I make use of SQL to auto-fill the Employee_ID column in Event_Table referencing to Employee_Table?

Desired Output:

```
Event_ID     Employee_ID    Employee_Name
    1             1             Rachel
    2             1             Rachel
    3             1             Rachel
    4             2             Jordan
```

Comment: Just use SQL but there is `DLookup` https://support.office.com/en-us/article/DLookup-Function-8896cb03-e31f-45d1-86db-bed10dca5937?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1

Comment: Set up a query instead of looking at the table itself. If you want to add the Employee_ID data to the Event table then use an Update query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a query, then you just use `inner join`:

```
select et.event_id, e.employee_id, e.employee_name,
from event_table as et join
     employee_table as e
     on et.employee_name = e.employee_name;
```

Comment: It sounds like the OP wants an `UPDATE` query that writes the `Employee_ID` into `Event_Table`. This is often unnecessary, as the OP could use the `SELECT ... INNER JOIN` you are proposing in most cases, instead of the single table. But in this case, the `JOIN` is being made on (what appears to be) a text field, which sounds like the `Events` table actually needs fixing.

Comment: Then should I use the UPDATE query to obtain my desired output?